# Can't run a Playlist App

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to run a small application with an HTML kit. It's simple, I have two forms one a text input form and the other a button. When you type your text and click the button the Event handler should save the text in a list. I even used window.onload but the text doesn't get saved in the list and displays on the page. I am using an outdated text editor for HTML but I wrote it in HTML5 so shouldn't it be backwards compatible? I loaded the page in google chrome and I run into the same problem.

Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/xcmdvg71/

Code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Playlist App</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<script>
  window.onload = init;
    function init() {
      var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
        button.onclick = handleButtonClick();
        }

    function handleButtonClick() {
        // acquire song through dom
        var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
        var songName = textInput.value;

        // create a new element for song
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = songName;
        var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
        ul.appendChild(li);
        }
</script>


</head>
<body>
            <form>
              <input type="text" id="songTextInput" size="40" placeholder="Song Name">
              <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Song">
            </form>

            <ul id="playlist">

            </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that click event doesn't work. 
Put alert in click function to check if event works. 
And may you instead of:

```
button.onclick = handleButtonClick();
```

use:

```
element.addEventListener('click',handleButtonClick,false)
```

Comment: Thanks mind explaining why button.onclick did not work but element.addEventListener did?